# How can I yield more than one partial in a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I asked a similar question recently, though that was aimed at having multiple blocks as arguments. This problem is a little more immediate.

The problem I have is, I have a helper method which I want to be able to pass content as a block to render. However, if I add more than one partial only the last one in the block is rendered. The methods are below.

```
  def bootrap_panel(title, klass = 'primary', &block)
    content_tag(:div, panel_heading(title) + panel_body(&block), class: 'panel panel-' + klass)
  end

  def panel_body(&block)
    content_tag(:div, yield, class: 'panel-body') if block_given?
  end
```

And an example of an issue I am having is here, where only the last partial is being displayed on the page.

```
=bootrap_panel 'Panels', 'primary' do
  - render "dynamic_panels/partials/new"
  - render "dynamic_panels/partials/dynamic_panels", dynamic_panels: dynamic_page.dynamic_panels
```

My first thought is, well I should be yielding the partials to an array or something first, then display that (I am not sure I am able to do that). Secondly, i am using the '-' operator instead of the '=' operator for displaying ruby content in haml. Why?

Comment: Did you try using `=` instead of `-` for your `render` calls? If yes, what happened?

Comment: if i switch them around, then the panel doesn't display, but both partials display!

Comment: So why don't you make them all `=` ?

Answer (score 3):

Pass the block itsef instead of its return value to content_tag:

```
content_tag(:div, class: 'panel-body', &block)
```

Other method:

```
content_tag(:div, capture(&block), class: 'panel-body')
```